Execution Plan keeps showing a missing Index when I have the index
I have already created the missing index on the table and the plan keeps telling me there is a missing index?
<MissingIndexes>
  <MissingIndexGroup Impact="10.6268">
    <MissingIndex Database="[OPTIONS]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[T_markets_quotes]">
      <ColumnGroup Usage="EQUALITY">
        <Column Name="[symbol]" ColumnId="5" />
      </ColumnGroup>
      <ColumnGroup Usage="INEQUALITY">
        <Column Name="[mid]" ColumnId="17" />
      </ColumnGroup>
      <ColumnGroup Usage="INCLUDE">
        <Column Name="[actual_runtime]" ColumnId="2" />
        <Column Name="[bid]" ColumnId="16" />
        <Column Name="[ask]" ColumnId="18" />
      </ColumnGroup>
    </MissingIndex>
  </MissingIndexGroup>
</MissingIndexes>

Here is the index that is created already:
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX1] ON [dbo].[T_markets_quotes]
(   [symbol] ASC,
    [mid] ASC
)
INCLUDE([actual_runtime],[bid],[ask]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) 
ON [PS_Monthly_Partition]([actual_runtime])
GO

Is something wrong with the execution plans?
I re-created the table and recreated all of the indexes but no luck getting the error to go away from the execution plan.

The index you have and the index it wants aren't exactly the same w.r.t. partition alignment. Please provide details of number of partitions in the table and the query that produces this warning (as requested when this was in staging ground)

Though TBH an impact of "10.6268" is pretty low and likely not worth the negative impact to maintenance of creating a non partition aligned index for a prospective 10% improvement on one specific query

+1  This estimated improvement isn't much, and the suggestion is to create a global index, and you created a partitioned index, which is physically one BTree index per partition.  Also consider that having a global index will block partition switching.

Rule of thumb: count the Missing Indexes as merely gentle suggestions to look at the query plan. Do NOT take them at face value and blindly add the index.

@MartinSmith. TY for this. So I was thinking about that but what is confusing is that when the 'Execution plan' gives you the 'Index Creation prompt' , when you right click and choose 'missing index details' it gives you the syntax without applying the index to the partitions, but when i review the index after creating it it applies it to the partitions ? So my question is that does SQL server always implicitly apply indexes to partitions even if you don't specify it in the syntax ? Because that's what it's doing ?

yeah If partition_scheme_name or filegroup isn't specified and the table is partitioned, the index is placed in the same partition scheme, using the same partitioning column, as the underlying table. - so I suppose the missing index suggestion could be clearer here that it doesn't want that default
